# using single database file for multiple users

Tags: sql-server, database

I want to make a site in which every user has his own customers and products to manage.
Whats the best way to handle this??

Is it OK to use an additional field for each entry specifying the user this entry belongs to ? or there is a better way?

Im using sql server if it matters.

Thank You.

Comment: Just as a pro-tip, some people might be put off answering you because of the awful answer rate you have. Also, the way you make this sound is that the idea is to have different databases for each user? Is that correct?

Comment: @Arran thank you very much brother :)
im new here and i didnt notice..

Comment: @Arran im trying to avoid creating a new database for each user..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do NOT I repeat do NOT** create a database per user, not even a table per user.
Add a column `UserID` to any table that may need  to reference a person with a product or order.

Comment: got it.. so the best way to do that is to add a field for each entry for specifying the UserId this entry belongs to, right ??

Answer (score 1):

not really much info in the question... however:

it is much simpler to scale some more data in a single database than to create additional databases.  so YES - make one database.

the exact schema you choose is more subtle - normalize, and link rows to appropriate users

Comment: got it.. so the best way to do that is to add a field for each entry for specifying the UserId this entry belongs to, right ??